# After upgrade to swift 3. Struct assignment not working as expected when release build , is this a Bug or my fault?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

My project using swift 3 on xcode 8.3.3 and xcode 9.They have same problem.Before convert to swift 3, using swift 2.3.3 * xcode 8.2 is Ok.

Problem : one function return a struct ,  but the value of stuct is not expected ,both default value.

ps:using inout can solve problem, but i still want to know the real reason.

I write a simple demo code :

```
import UIKit


protocol EncodingProtocol {
    mutating func decodeFromStream()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let ip: EventIpRes = EventIpRes()
    ip.decodeFromStream()

    print("111 \(ip.m_ip)")

    }
}

struct IpInfo : EncodingProtocol { 

    var ip: Int = 0

    mutating func decodeFromStream() {
        ip = 110110110
    }
}

class EventIpRes : EncodingProtocol{// #2. not impelement EncodingProtocol, everything is ok.

    var m_ip = IpInfo()

    func decodeFromStream(){
        let testIp = ProtoBufSerializer.decodeStruct(event: m_ip) as! IpInfo
        print("222 \(testIp)") // #0. Problem: testIp is default value..

        m_ip = testIp
    }
}

class ProtoBufSerializer {

    class func decodeStruct(event: EncodingProtocol)-> EncodingProtocol{
        // print("33 \(event)")// #1. uncomment this line, everything is ok.

        var new = event
        new.decodeFromStream()
        return new
    }

}
```

#0. Problem: testIp is default value..

some test I've tried :

- build configuration : debug is ok ,release mode has problem.
- release build , swift compiler optimization level：fast，whole module optimization has problem，others are ok.

#1. add a print statement in function , everything is ok.

#2. not impelement EncodingProtocol, everything is ok.

PS: Although demo code looks strange, but i think it is correct in grammar. it should work fine.....

Comment: PS: Although demo code looks strange, but i think it is correct in grammar. it should work fine.

Comment: I can reproduce. — Basically, I would say any time you get different output from Debug vs. Release configuration, that's a bug that Apple wants to hear about. File at http://bugs.swift.org

Comment: (Or when inserting a `print` statement changes the output, that's a bug. Basically what's happening is that something is being wrongly optimized away by the compiler.)

Comment: @matt, thanks for replying. I'll report the problem to apple. :)

Comment: No problem. It's an excellent demo, you've done a great job.

Comment: fixed in https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/12234

Comment: Thank you for reporting back!